# DataGridComboBoxColumn value resets after selection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following DataGrid control, which potentially should show:

Checkbox (to select), Combobox (to select action), Column 1 (from Database), Column 2 (from Database)

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgDatabase" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="299" Width="819">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="dgIsTested" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="dgProposedDataType" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Window Load Function (as soon as the WPF application opens and loads)

```
 private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Connect to SQL Database
            connObj = new SqlConnection(connection);
            cmdObj = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS", connObj);
            daAdapObj = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdObj);
            daAdapObj.Fill(dsObj, "Table");
            String[] myArray = { "Generic", "Number", "Date" }; 

            dgDatabase.ItemsSource = dsObj.Tables["Table"].DefaultView;
            dgProposedDataType.ItemsSource = myArray;
            }
```

Now, there are two issues I'm facing:

1. The combobox appears blank, when I double click it appears on the grid and then I make my choice. But as soon as I click away to the next grid item, the choice goes blank.
2. Can I re-order the bound and unbound columns: Checkbox, Column1, Column2, Combobox?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the columns however you want by setting the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false` and define the columns in the order you want them to appear:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgDatabase" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="299" Width="819"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="dgIsTested" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TABLE_NAME}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding COLUMN}" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="dgProposedDataType" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

For the selection in the `ComboBox` to become saved, you need a column to store the value in:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="dgProposedDataType" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding YourColumn}" />
```

You have to add this column to your `DataTable` if it's not part of your `SELECT` statement:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Connect to SQL Database
    connObj = new SqlConnection(connection);
    cmdObj = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS", connObj);
    daAdapObj = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdObj);
    daAdapObj.Fill(dsObj, "Table");

    var table = dsObj.Tables["Table"];
    table.Columns.Add("YourColumn");
    dgDatabase.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;

    String[] myArray = { "Generic", "Number", "Date" };
    dgProposedDataType.ItemsSource = myArray;
}
```

Comment: Works wonderful! QQ before I mark it - how do I set one of the items in myArray as the default selected value? @mm8

Comment: You set the cell of the DataTable. But please ask a new question if you have another issue.